# onClick insert or append text into a textarea

Tags: jquery

I'd like to get this right without wasting any more time on posts that seem they almost answer it, but don't. Thanks for your help.
I want to click Book and have the value of 'lit:' entered or appended into a text area named Discussion in which some text already resides. Please correct my errors so my four remaining brain cells can be happy. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<php $m=1;?>

<Book>Book</Book>
<textarea name="Discussion[]" class="cleanup mceEditor" 
id="Discussion<?php echo $m;?>"><?php echo $row_review['Discussion']; ?></textarea>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("Book").click(function(){
      $("#Discussion<?php echo $m;$m++;?>").val('lit:');
   }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Is anything happening when you click the button? Is all the text replaced, or nothing changes? If it's the latter, it may have to do with you using Tiny MCE. I know some of those type of types of plugins read from the textarea once when loaded, and then ignore any changes to them because it is managing the content elsewhere.

Comment: I'll check that right now. Nope, no joy.

Comment: So, are you using TinyMCE? If so, that is why none of this stuff is working. See my answer below.

Comment: Okay, I'll recheck it. edit
That looks truly interesting. Does it go into the tinymce.js file or somewhere on the page?

Comment: I wonder if the click event occurs?  Is the `Book` element actually being rendered like that? - you could test it with an alert inside the handle before anything else just to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the only issue is that you want it to append the text instead of replacing it, you could do something like this in the onclick function:

```
var $elm = $("#Discussion<?php echo $m;$m++;?>")
$elm.val($elm.val() + 'lit:');
```

This will append "lit:" to the textarea.

Comment: okay, let me give that a shot. gotta warm up my coffee first.

Comment: I was going to type something like this so +1 even though objects which start with $ always make my eyes retrack to check.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm going with this as the approved answer, though something else must be wrong on my page. I've tried every good snippet I've found today and none of them work. Thanks for your time and snippet.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, I don't know if it is a common or good practice but I always put a $ before my jQuery objects so that I can easily see if it is a DOM object or a jQuery object.

Comment: @Supericy - if it is YOUR practice, then that works. I just have my own personal bias and I see that done quite a bit that way, and it is absolutely a valid way to name stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using TinyMCE (an assumption I'm making based on the mceEditor class you have in your code), you will need to do something like this:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'lit:');
```

That will insert the "lit:" text at where ever the cursor is at. You can be fancier if you want, and add in undos:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceBeginUndoLevel');
tinyMCE.selectedInstance.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'lit:');
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceEndUndoLevel');
```

Comment: That looks truly interesting. Does it go into the tinymce.js file or somewhere on the page?

Comment: I don't have tinyMCE available to test, but I think that the tinyMCE variable is setup to point at whatever the active tinyMCE instance is. You should be to put it in your $("Book").click(function(){ }); section, instead of the $("#Discussion<?php echo $m;$m++;?>").val('lit:'); code.

Comment: Okay, thanks all. Let me work with your ideas for a bit and see if I can make it go. A bow to you all.

Comment: Okay, well the update is that even a 'hello world' alert isn't working, though I have a good link to google in the page. Totally confused, but thanks again.

Comment: This tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'lit:'); is starting to work, but it is going into the last text area on the page and I work on figuring out how to get it into the appropriate one. More later...

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994269/multiple-tinymce - Looks like you just specify the id of the textarea to specify which textarea you want to execute the command on: tinymce.get('TEXT_AREA_ID').execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'lit:'); - So instead of selectedInstance you would probably use tinyMCE.get('Discussion<?php echo $m;$m++;?>').execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'lit:');